# Counting the number of unique words in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using the following code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899925, I am able to find if a word is unique or not (by comparing if it was used once or greater than once):

```
helloString = ['hello', 'world', 'world']
count = {}
for word in helloString :
   if word in count :
      count[word] += 1
   else:
      count[word] = 1
```

But, if I were to have a string with hundreds of words, how would I be able to count the number of unique words within that string?

For example, my code has:

```
uniqueWordCount = 0
helloString = ['hello', 'world', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
count = {}
for word in words :
   if word in count :
      count[word] += 1
   else:
      count[word] = 1
```

How would I be able to set `uniqueWordCount` to `6`? Usually, I am really good at solving these types of algorithmic puzzles, but I have been unsuccessful with figuring this one out. I feel as if it is right beneath my nose.

Comment: There are 6 unique words, not 5

Comment: 7 unique words not 6

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to use the `set` collection type. A `set` is a collection in which all elements are unique. Therefore:

```
unique = set([ 'one', 'two', 'two']) 
len(unique) # is 2
```

You can use a set from the outset, adding words to it as you go:

```
unique.add('three')
```

This will throw out any duplicates as they are added. Or, you can collect all the elements in a list and pass the list to the `set()` function, which will remove the duplicates at that time. The example I provided above shows this pattern:

```
unique = set([ 'one', 'two', 'two'])
unique.add('three')

# unique now contains {'one', 'two', 'three'}
```

[Read more about sets in Python.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set-types-set-frozenset)

Answer (score 8):

You have many options for this, I recommend a set, but you can also use a counter, which counts the amount a number shows up, or you can look at the number of keys for the dictionary you made.

---

## Set

You can also convert the list to a set, where all elements have to be unique. Not unique elements are discarded:

```
helloString = ['hello', 'world', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
helloSet = set(helloString) #=> ['doing', 'how', 'are', 'world', 'you', 'hello', 'today']
uniqueWordCount = len(set(helloString)) #=> 7
```

Here's a link to further reading on [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

## Counter

You can also use a counter, which can also tell you how often a word was used, if you still need that information.

```
from collections import Counter

helloString = ['hello', 'world', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
counter = Counter(helloString)
len(counter) #=> 7
counter["world"] #=> 2
```

## Loop

At the end for your loop, you can check the `len` of `count`, also, you mistyped `helloString` as `words`:

```
uniqueWordCount = 0
helloString = ['hello', 'world', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
count = {}
for word in helloString:
   if word in count :
      count[word] += 1
   else:
      count[word] = 1
len(count) #=> 7
```

Comment: Your loop version just replicates what a set does, since a set is basically a dictionary with ignored values.

Comment: @jamylax, yes, but I included it incase the OP wanted a more verbose one (exactly why I also included a set). I moved the loop example to the button.

Comment: there is no reason for `count` to be a dictionary if you only set values always to `True`. Change it to a `set`

Comment: @jamylak I used a dict since the OP used a dict. If he wants to try the set version **instead** then that's fine. I changed my answer to have minimal changes to the OP's original code.

Comment: Now it makes sense because you are using the values of a dictionary

Comment: Yes the counter does all of that, and the set gets to the result more directly

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections.Counter`

```
helloString = ['hello', 'world', 'world']

from collections import Counter

c = Counter(helloString)

print("There are {} unique words".format(len(c)))
print('They are')

for k, v in c.items():
    print(k)
```

I know the question doesn't specifically ask for this, but to maintain order

```
helloString = ['hello', 'world', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today']

from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

c = OrderedCounter(helloString)

print("There are {} unique words".format(len(c)))
print('They are')

for k, v in c.items():
    print(k)
```

Comment: I don't know, maybe someone thought I copied. I didn't. But as you answered first and these answers are essentially the same I don't mind withdrawing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your current code you can either increment `uniqueWordCount` in the `else` case where you already set `count[word]`, or just lookup the number of keys in the dictionary: [`len(count)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len).

If you only want to know the number of unique elements, then get the elements in the `set`: [`len(set(helloString))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a set.

```
def stuff(helloString):
    hello_set = set(helloString)
    return len(hello_set)
```

Comment: Same thing *as what*? Do you mean as the same answer that you posted as I was writing mine and therefore couldn't see this page? Thanks for pointing that out. For the record, I did upvote your answer...

Comment: Thought you said "instead of using". My bad. Removed the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Counter is the efficient way to do it.
This code is similar to counter,

```
text = ['hello', 'world']

# create empty dictionary
freq_dict = {}
 
# loop through text and count words
for word in text:
    # set the default value to 0
    freq_dict.setdefault(word, 0)
    # increment the value by 1
    freq_dict[word] += 1
 


for key,value in freq_dict.items():
    if value == 1:
         print(f'Word "{key}" has single appearance in the list')
```

```
Word "hello" has single appearance in the list
Word "world" has single appearance in the list

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score -1):

I may be misreading the question but I believe the goal is to find all elements which only occur one time in the list.

```
from collections import Counter
helloString = ['hello', 'world', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
counter = Counter(helloString)
uniques = [value for value, count in counter.items() if count == 1]
```

This will give us 6 items because "world" occurs twice in our list:

```
>>> uniques
['you', 'are', 'doing', 'how', 'today', 'hello']
```