# Number of unique words in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find out the number of unique words in a DataFrame.

The dataset is very large, that's why following method gives me an error:

```
vec = CountVectorizer()
m = vec.fit_transform(df['text'])
a = m.toarray()

MemoryError: Unable to allocate __. TiB for an array with shape (__, __) and data type int64
```

DataFrame example:

```
id  text
1   ['alan', 'smithee', 'steht', 'pseudonym', 'fuer', 'fiktiven', 'regisseur']
2   ['das', 'pseudonym', 'entstand', 'infolge', 'arbeiten', 'western', 'film']
3   ['der', 'film', 'trug', 'abschluss', 'arbeiten', 'deutlich', 'tottens']
```

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html

Comment: Is there any reason you can't continue operating with the sparse matrix `m`? More info on sparse matrices [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#module-scipy.sparse)

Comment: Is there a way to find out the number of unique words through the sparse matrix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the number of unique words in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726361/counting-the-number-of-unique-words-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than building a new construct (NumPy array) with all of its overhead, I suggest that you extract the words from the DF and make a simple count with

```
len(set( <here you extract the words> ))
```

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Please explain your solution further if you don't mind.

Comment: Where do you not understand?  I'm assuming that you know how to access values in your DF.  Since you didn't supply any data frame to illustrate the format, there's no way I can go into more detail on that part.

Comment: How to access the values and count the unique words. I've edited my Question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I showed you how to count the unique words; how to access values is part of any tutorial on PANDAS.  How to combine or stream those lists of words would be built from any tutorial on lists.  It seems that you need a follow-up question for the problems you have with the code you've written to do that.

Comment: Got it, took a while