# word count in all files using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, word-count

I want to get word frequency per file in all files in a folder.
However, it did not work.

### The error was as follows:

C:\Python\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Python/Anaconda3/frequency.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Anaconda3/frequency.py", line 6, in 
    for word in file.read().split():
NameError: name 'file' is not defined

### Process finished with exit code 1

How can I make it effectively?
Thank you.

```
import glob
import os
path = 'C:\Python\Anaconda3'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    wordcount = {}
    for word in file.read().split():
        if word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] += 1
print(word, wordcount)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you sure glob alows widlcards? Do you not need open('file) before reading it?

Comment: *this code does not work* is not a useful problem description. In what way **specifically** does it **not work**? The [help/on-topic] says very clearly *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Maybe [this could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899878/counting-unique-words-in-python?rq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726361/counting-the-number-of-unique-words-in-a-list?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Edit the question with all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code stands, you have three obvious errors (although there may be more).

1. You have a `for` loop where you change the name of the iterator

   ```
   for **filename** in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
       ...
       for word in **file**.read.split():
           ...
   ```
2. The `wordcount` dictionary gets re-initialized (and thus erased) in each iteration of your for loop. You can fix this two ways depending on what you are trying to get at:

   a. Move the line `wordcount={}` to before you start your `for` loops to prevent clearing out the dictionary after each file. This will give you a total `wordcount` for all files.

   b. Append `wordcount` to another dictionary `files` after each iteration of your loop, that way you have a dictionary where the keys are filenames, and the values are dictionaries containing your wordcounts. This can be a bit confusing, because you now have a dictionary of dictionaries. Referencing individual wordcounts becomes `filecounts[filename][word] = count`.
3. Your method of printing dictionaries is incorrect, consider the following instead:

   ```
   for word in wordcount:
       print('{word}:\t{count}'.format(word=word, count=wordcount[word]))
   ```

I would also suggest using a default dictionary (see [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), this would eliminate the need to check if a `word` is in the dictionary, and set it to `1`.

So, in total, I would write it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import glob
import os

path = 'C:\Python\Anaconda3'
filecounts = {}

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    wordcount = defaultdict(int)
    for word in filename.read().split():
        wordcount[word] += 1

    filecounts[filename] = wordcount

for filename in filecounts:
    print('Word count for file \'{file}\''.format(file=filename))
    for word in filecounts[filename]:
        print('\t{word}:\t{count}'.format(word=word, count=filecounts[filename][word]))
```

Comment: The line 'print('Word count for file \'{file}'\'.format(file=filename))' did not work, so that I edited it as 'print("Word count for file\t", filename)'. Anyway, I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Nice catch, the escape characters always get me.

Comment: You can avoid the `defaultdict` by using a regular dict with `dict.get` instead of normal lookups. `wordcount = {}; wordcount[word] = wordcount.get(word, 0) + 1`

Comment: It seems more intuitive. Thank you !

Comment: @AdamSmith What is the benefit of your form? If anything, it seems less idiomatic? Is there a benefit that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @MichaelMolter Just dropping a stdlib import, that's all. I'd rather not import `defaultdict` if this is its only use. YMMV :)